# Como fazer a segurança por perfil com Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou criando um sistema usando Asp.Net MVC e antes de começar preciso fazer a segurança baseada em perfil. Vou ter vários perfis cada um com uma opção de acesso. Por exemplo: Perfil Administrador (acessa tudo), Perfil Comum (acesso restrito), Perfil Avançado (alguns acesso administrativo), etc.

Pensei em criar o perfil e criar os modulos(metodos ou controllers) para o perfil e atraves de um boolean true/false dar permissoes ao perfil e depois colocar o perfil ao usuario, isso ao meu ver seria a maneira mais simples de fazer. Porém, eu não sei como fazer isso checando se o metodo/controller eh permitido ou nao pelo perfil para ter acesso como por exemplo dar baixa em uma conta q seria apenas o perfil Administrador que poderia fazer, ou como uma baixa de venda que o Perfil Avançado poderia fz tbm junto com o Administrador.

Como fazer isso ? o que sugerem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensando em uma solução bem simples você poderia usar o `Filter` do ASP.NET.

**Banco de dados**

Você poderá ter 3 tabelas, uma de usuários, outra de perfil, e outra perfil usuário.

**Controller**

Você ira anotar suas classes ou métodos com o nome do filter, aqui você dirá quais perfis terá acesso a classe.

```
[PerfilFiltro(Perfil = "Vendas")]
```

**Classe filtro**

Dai na classe do filter, você acessara o banco para verificar se o usuario em questão tem ou não o perfil para acessar a classe.

```
public class PerfilFiltro : ActionFilterAttribute { 
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
        if (!filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(Perfil))
        {
            string Usuario = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["NomeUsuario"].ToString();

            // o parâmetro Perfil é o perfil anotado na classe

            // use sua logica para buscar o perfil vinculado a este usuario
            // caso ele não tenha acesso você pode redireciona-lo para uma 
            // pagina de erro/ou sem permissão.
        }
     }   
}
```

Comment: vc tem algum exemplo um pouco mais detalhado ?

Comment: Qual nível de detalhe você precisa? por que acho, que com o que você especificou, isto ai resolve, basta criar um painel administrativo para isto, algumas tabelas no banco de dados e pronto. Aqui = https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters   tem um exemplo que talvez te ajude.

Comment: Você terá que adaptar a logica para o que você precisa. Se não for algo grande, isto ai resolve bem.

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou bastante